# NZEC Error in AWK programming

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to solve the SPOJ problem [SIZECON](http://www.spoj.com/problems/SIZECON/) using the awk programming language.Using the below code

```
awk ' {
    t = $1;
    while ( t-- ) { 
        getline b;
        x + b * (b > 0);
        print x;
    }
    exit;
}'
```

OUTPUT:

```
4(No.of test cases)
5
5
-5
5
6
11
-1
11
```

The Expected INPUT and OUTPUT is: 
**Input:**

```
4
5
-5
6
-1
```

**Output:**

```
11
```

the code works perfectly fine on my linux system and getting error when submitting in spoj (NZEC ERROR).Can anyone help me ?Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you also give the input data, and what rules to get the output.  I have learned here that you should avoid using  `getline`, since there are so many pitfall.

Comment: Is that the output you want or the output you get that you don't want? Just post sample input, expected output, and the specific error message you're getting so we don't have to wander off through other web sites researching your problem.

Comment: I never knew that there is pitfall of using getline. I m new to awk programming.anyway thanks for info..

Comment: @EdMorton Its the expected Output.And this is the expected Input and Output Input:
4
5
-5
6
-1
Output:
11

Comment: Please edit your question to provide the missing information (including the exact error message you are getting) as you can't put formatted text in comments. Also explain WHY that's the expected output. FYI, if youre ever considering using getline, make sure you read and fully understand everything discussed at http://awk.info/?tip/getline first.

Comment: you're print `x` at each iteration. Move it to an awk `END{print x}` block. Good luck.

Comment: You haven't really written an awk script. Instead you've treated awk like a regular procedural language, which it is not. It has a `pattern {action}` structure that you should use. Something like `awk 'NR == 1 {next} $1 > 0 {sum += $1} END {print sum}'`

Comment: As for your submission problem, are you just submitting the part between the single quotes? That's the script that you should submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be what you want:

```
$ awk 'NR<2{t=$0;next} $0>0{s+=$0} NR>t{print s+0;exit}' file
11
```

I originally was just going to test for t having a value but the requirements on that site just say it will be less than 1000 so I guess it could be zero.

Also you need to print `s+0` to ensure you get a numeric value instead of a null string if `t` is zero or the file is empty.

`NR<2` tests for the first input line. It would be more naturally written as `NR==1` but I understand you are looking for brevity over clarity.

awk scripts are made of a series of `<condition> { <action> }` segments, wrapped in an implicit `while read` loop so the posted script is equivalent to this pseudo-code in a procedural language:

```
while read line from file
do
    lineNr++
    if (lineNr < 2) {
        t=$0
        next
    }
    if (line > 0) {
        s+=$0
    }
    if (lineNr > t) {
        print s+0
        exit
    }
done
```

I think you should be able to figure the rest out given that and with google and the awk man pages when needed.

Comment: Will you explain me ? I couldn't able to understand But ts working prefectly.

Comment: I added an explanation. You should get the book Effective Awk Programming, Third Edition, by Arnold Robbins if you're going to be doing any other text manipulation.

Comment: I edited the question back to my original question.The answer one you gave is the my expected answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Given the set of integers, find the sum of all positive integers in it.

This is what you're doing? Seems pretty simple:

```
awk '
    {
        if ( NR == 1 ) {
            total_to_read = $0 + 1
            next
        }
        if ( $0 > 0 ) total += $0
        if ( total_to_read == NR ) {
            print total
            exit
        }
    }' test.txt
```

The `END` phase is what you want to do at the end of the loop. I am simply taking each element in the loop and adding it to `total` if it's greater than 0.

---

> It's not that simple. He needs to only read the number of values specified by the integer on the first line of input and he needs the briefest possible solution (excepting white space) - Ed Morton

My original answer was to show that you were overthinking Awk. Awk does the loop for you.

I've modified the above program to include the *read the first number* requirement. No more `END` needed. I save the first value, and go to the `next` line. When I get to the total lines to read, I print out that total, and do `exit` which should end my loop.

You can see this is actually equivalent to the *psuedo-code* given in [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694581/368630) answer. It should be easier to understand.

Ed Morton pointed out that Awk can have a series of `<expression> {code}` segments. I always knew you could have one, but never thought of doing it multiple times.

This means that I could use this to *imply* if statements instead of spelling them out. Making your code a wee bit shorter:

```
awk '
    ( NR == 1 ) {
        total_to_read = $1 + 1
        next
    }
    ( $0 > 0 ) {total += $0}
    ( total_to_read == NR ) {
        print total
        exit
    }' test.txt
```

To make it even shorter, we could use shorter variable names. Let's use `t` for `total_to_read` and `s` for `total`:

```
awk '
    ( NR == 1 ) {
        t = $1 + 1
        next
    }
    ( $0 > 0 ) {s += $0}
    ( t == NR ) {
        print s
        exit
    }' test.txt
```

A few more tweaks. Instead of equals `NR == 1`, I'll do `NR < 2`. `NR` is the number of records, and if you are talking about `NR` being less than 2, it **has** to be 1. You can't have zero or negative number of records in your implied `awk` loop.

In my original program, I was adding `1` to `t` (total lines to read), then testing to exit if `t == NR`. If I don't add `1` to the total lines to read, I save a few characters, and I can test `t > NR` which saves another character:

```
awk '
    ( NR < 2 ) {
        t = $0
        next
    }
    ( $0 > 0 ) {s += $0}
    ( t > NR ) {
        print s
        exit
    }' test.txt
```

Now, let's eliminate all that useless whitespace and cram it all together!

```
awk 'NR<2{t=$0;next} $0>0{s+=$0} NR>t{print s+0;exit}' test.txt
```

And, I get [Ed Morton's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25694581/368630) answer...  Damn.

Well, at least I hope you understand this step-by-step explanation, and understand how Ed Morton's solution works.

Comment: It's not that simple. He needs to only read the number of values specified by the integer on the first line of input and he needs the briefest possible solution (excepting white space).

Comment: @EdMorton  Yes, I missed those requirements. I wasn't as much as attempting to give an actual solution, but to lead the OP to a solution. The OP's answer ignored Awk's implied loop which just makes things a lot more complex.